# remove the first letter if it is 'R' by using php .. HOW?

Tags: php, regex, if-statement

I tried to remove the first letter if it is 'r' for example by using `ltrim` function, but it didn't work.

How can check if the first letter if the word 'r' or 'n' etc, by using "if"

```
<?php
    $string = "no";

    if (ltrim($string ,'r')) {
        echo 'Yes';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String elements can be accessed like it's an array ...

```
if(strtolower($string[0]) == 'r'){
    $string = substr($string, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a one liner, everyone else used substring, here is something different:

```
preg_replace('/(^[Rr])/', '', $string);
```

**Edit**

The above will replace it, misunderstood the question. Here you can do the if:

```
if(preg_match('/(^[Rr])/', $string)){
   echo "Yes";   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if($str[0] == 'r') {
    $str = substr($str, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
if(strtolower(substr($string, 0, 1)) === 'r')
{
    //do something
}
```

to remove the first letter:

```
$str = substr($string, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
<?php
$string = "no";
if(substr($string ,0,1) == 'n'){
    echo 'Yes';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

ltrim is used to remove whitespaces or other predefined character from the left side of a string. You can check string first character using this :

```
$string = "no";
if($string[0] == 'r'){
  echo "yes";
}
```

See [DEMO](http://codepad.org/BpHoAgXW)